# Neo4j connection to service (.Net)

Tags: c#, neo4j

I can't get access to Neo4j Database (version 2.2.1 commmunity). 
I'm trying

```
GraphClient client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
```

and

```
GraphClient client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://neo4j@neo4j.localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
```

I always have the same problem

```
{
  "errors" : 
   [ {
    "message" : "Invalid authorization token supplied.",
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
   } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
```

Note that it is also possible to remove the authentication requirement by changing a line in **neo4j.server.properties** found in the **conf** directory. The line should be

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

See [the Neo4j manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html#security-server-auth).